# jQuery svg, implementing interactive objects

Tags: jquery, xml, svg

I have a code which creates an object in my svg file:

```
<![CDATA[
var canc=0;
var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
function create(){
var C=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle")
C.setAttributeNS(null,"r",50)
document.documentElement.appendChild(C)
}
]]>
```

I would like to implement a function which deletes this element by making a `mouseover` event in other element. How can I do it? Thanks!

---

```
<![CDATA[
var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
function create(){
...
canc = C;
return canc;
} 

function remove(evt){
var node=evt.target
node.parentNode.removeChild(canc)
}
```

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to your title, post the solution as an *answer* and, when you're able, *accept* that answer, or a better one, as the solution when you're able. For more information as to *why*, please read this, from [meta]: '[Is it ok to add solved to the title of a qustion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)'.